# Duress capability to clear hard drive encryption keys making disk unrecoverable in Windows?

Tags: disk-encryption

I need to create a "duress" capability on a Linux-based and a Windows-based computer that have encrypted drives.  I assume the easiest and quickest way would be to blow away the keys.  On the Linux, LUKS encryption has a simple command to clear the key slots making the drive unrecoverable.  Is there a disk encryption tool for Windows that provides a method to clear the key slots, or perhaps a way to clear the TPM?

Comment: I googled "windows clear TPM" and got this from the official Windows documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/security/hardware-protection/tpm/initialize-and-configure-ownership-of-the-tpm#clear-all-the-keys-from-the-tpm

Comment: Modern storage devices with SED capability can also instantly wipe all the data by deleting a key used transparently for encryption.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to microsoft...trustedplatformmodule/clear-tpm.view=win10-psYes, that would be great, but sadly, these are not SED.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Clear-Tpm` Powershell commandlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/trustedplatformmodule/clear-tpm?view=win10-ps) to do this programmatically, rather than using the TPM management control snap-in.

You could also use ATA Secure Erase on any modern SSD. [This tutorial](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase) shows you how to trigger an ATA secure erase command on Linux. For Windows you'd need to write your own code to send the ATA commands to the disk - you'll need to consult [the ATA command reference](http://www.t13.org/documents/UploadedDocuments/docs2006/e05179r4-ACS-SecurityClarifications.pdf) (section 1.8 explains how to use SECURE ERASE) and [do some DeviceIoControl calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070987/sending-ata-commands-directly-to-device-in-windows) to execute those commands.

Comment: ATA Security Erase also works on HDDs, not just SSDs. Now that most modern drives of all types support SED, the erasure is extremely quick.